# Move data from columns into new rows in dataset

Tags: spss

I have a database that contains repetitive variables in the same row. I need a syntax to copy values from certain variables in the database to a new row in the same database to specific variables.
So if I have variables: ***V1a, V1b, V1c, V2a, V2b, V2c***, I want to create a new row in database where ***V1a, V1b*** and **V1c** would contain values from ***V2a, V2b*** and **V2c**.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide us with a reproducable example, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you are asking If you added a table with some sample data, and another table with the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to restructure the file so that for `a` `b` and `c`, `V1` and `V2` won't be separated into separate columns but into separate rows.

Here's how you can do it -

first you can run this to create a small demonstration dataset:

```
data list list/V1a V1b V1c V2a V2b V2c (6f6).
begin data
1 2 3 11 22 33
6 7 8 66 77 88
end data.
```

Now for the restructure:

```
varstocases /make a from V1a V2a
            /make b from V1b V2b
            /make c from V1c V2c
            /index=source(a).
Compute source=char.substr(source,1,2).
```

The column `source` has the name of the original column.